# Using preg_match many time to check if strings are in text

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, str-replace

I have a text from a text area, which contains 4 necessary strings. Before I insert this text on the database I check for the presence of those strings.

Is there a better and alternative way than do 4 `preg_match` operations, maybe using `preg_match_all`?

If I'd like to replace those 4 `strings` with something else, where is the difference between `preg_replace` and `str_replace`. Which should I use?

Here my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['text'])){
    $text= $link->real_escape_string($_POST['text']);

    $string = $text;
    $pattern1 = '/LIMITE_TYPE/';
    $pattern2 = '/LIMITE_SET/';
    $pattern3 = '/TODAY_PRICE/';
    $pattern4 = '/AUTO_SIGN/';

    if(preg_match($pattern1, $string)
       && preg_match($pattern2, $string)
       && preg_match($pattern3, $string)
       && preg_match($pattern4, $string))
    {
        echo 'ok';
    }else{
        echo 'not found';
    }

    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You only want to check the presence of exact words, you don't need to use regex, use `strpos` instead that is faster:

```
$word1 = 'LIMITE_TYPE';
$word2 = 'LIMITE_SET';
$word3 = 'TODAY_PRICE';
$word4 = 'AUTO_SIGN';

if  ( (strpos($string, $word1)
    && strpos($string, $word2)
    && strpos($string, $word3)
    && strpos($string, $word4))!==false) {
```

But if you really need patterns (with regex features inside):

```
$patterns = array('~\bLIMITE_TYPE\b~',
                  '~\bLIMITE_SET\b~',
                  '~\bTODAY_PRICE\b~',
                  '~\bAUTO_SIGN\b~'); 
$found = true;
foreach($pattern as $pattern) {
    if (!preg_match($pattern, $string)) {
        $found = false;
        break;
    }
}
echo ($found)? 'ok' : 'not found';
```

The advantage of these codes is that tests stop at the first false result.

Answer (score 1):

You can search faster with str_pos:

```
$string = $text;
$pattern1 = 'LIMITE_TYPE';
$pattern2 = 'LIMITE_SET';
$pattern3 = 'TODAY_PRICE';
$pattern4 = 'AUTO_SIGN';

$patterns = array($pattern1, $pattern2, $pattern3, $pattern4);

if (strpos($pattern1, $text) && strpos($pattern2, $text) ... etc )
{   
    str_replace($patterns, $string, $text); //replace  patterns with string on text
}
```

I think that this is the faster way but not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

there is no function that can do what you want in one call, but you could use a loop, that also makes replacing much easier.
Also you dont need regex, the normal string functions already do what you need

```
$string = $text;
$patterns = array(
    'LIMITE_TYPE' => 'REPLACEMENT1',
    'LIMITE_SET' => 'REPLACEMENT2',
    'TODAY_PRICE' => 'REPLACEMENT3',
    'AUTO_SIGN' => 'REPLACEMENT4'
);

// check if they are all there:
$valid = true;
foreach($patterns as $pattern => $replacement)
{
    if(strpos($string, $pattern) === false) {
        $valid = false;
        break;
    }
}
if($valid)
{
    // replace them
    foreach($patterns as $pattern => $replacement)
    {
        $string = str_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
    }
}
else
{
    // not valid
}
```